# Marionette not navigating to the same url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have the following marionette app: http://slexy.org/view/s21ARG2QdP

My problem is that when I select the node in the tree, I get "selected" and "routed" alerts.

But when I select the node again I see only "selected".

Somehow I don't get into the controller function if I go to the same url.

Is anyone has an idea what am I missing?

Thanks, Alex A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct. Your "problem" comes from implementation of [`Backbone.History.navigate(fragment, options)`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-196).

Let's look into it:

```
navigate: function(fragment, options) {
  if (!History.started) return false;
  if (!options || options === true) options = {trigger: !!options};

  // Normalize the fragment.
  fragment = this.getFragment(fragment || '');

  // Don't include a trailing slash on the root.
  var root = this.root;
  if (fragment === '' || fragment.charAt(0) === '?') {
    root = root.slice(0, -1) || '/';
  }
  var url = root + fragment;

  // Strip the hash and decode for matching.
  fragment = decodeURI(fragment.replace(pathStripper, ''));

  if (this.fragment === fragment) return;
  this.fragment = fragment;
  // Truncated 
  ....
  ....
}
```

From here you can see that when current fragment is equal to new fragment `Backbone.History.navigate()` function will exit, and because of that it will not trigger your controller's action.

---

I think that this approach is right way to handle routing and if you need to some kind "refresh" for the current view you can use one of the several technics:

1. Full page refresh.
2. Manually call controller's action.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. And is there a chance I can refresh one region in the page instead of calling the controller's action?

Comment: Sure. Just listen for your event and show region with new data.